# Writing NSOperation-friendly methods

Tags: iphone, ios, nsoperation

I have an object (`Processor`) containing several methods that perform lengthy calculations. I'd like to use those methods both on the main thread and in `NSOperation` subclasses.

Inside my `NSOperation` subclass code I repeatedly call `isCancelled`, so cancellation is fairly responsive. However, when the operation calls one of those lengthy `Processor` methods, it isn't able to respond to  cancellation until that method returns.

Is there a good way to write methods so they can be used both with and without operations? I'm considering adding an `operation` argument to my CPU-intensive `Processor` methods and writing them like this:

```
- (void)calculateWithOperation:(NSOperation *)operation {
    do {
        if (operation != nil && [operation isCancelled]) {
            return;
        }
        // Do some more calculation...
    } while (! finished);
}

// For convenient main thread execution.
- (void)calculate {
    [self calculateWithOperation:nil];
}
```

Has anyone else run into this issue before? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

The only way for an NSOperation to respond to canceling is to check if it's isCancelled as frequently as feasible. After all, it's just a thread which needs to exit when a flag is set. Basically, the isCancelled infrastructure is needed to gracefully free the operation's resources. So I'd say you just have to pepper the expensive method with checks.